# Parse HTML table to JSON using Jsoup in Java

Tags: html, json, html-table, jsoup, html-parsing

I have an HTML table that is formatted like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Book1</td>
            <td>Group1</td>
            <td>Code1</td>
            <td>Lesson1</td>
            <td>Day1</td>
            <td>Day2</td>
            <td>Day3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Book2</td>
            <td>Group2</td>
            <td>Code2</td>
            <td>Lesson2</td>
            <td>Day1</td>
            <td>Day2</td>
            <td>Day3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to parse this HTML with Jsoup, and output a JSON string formatted like this:

```
{
   "Book1": {
      "Group": "Group1",
      "Code": "Code1",
      "Lesson": "Lesson1",
      "Day1": "Day1",
      "Day2": "Day2",
      "Day3": "Day3"
   },
   "Book2": {
      "Group": "Group2",
      "Code": "Code2",
      "Lesson": "Lesson2",
      "Day1": "Day1",
      "Day2": "Day2",
      "Day3": "Day3"
   }
}
```

I tried this code:

```
public String TableToJson(String source) throws JSONException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            String Name = tds.get(0).text();
            String Group = tds.get(1).text();
            String Code = tds.get(2).text();

            jsonObject.put("Name", Name); 
            jsonObject.put("Group", Group);
            jsonObject.put("Code", Code);
            list.put(jsonObject);
        }
    }
    return list.toString();
}
```

But it returned the wrong result:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Book1",
        "Group": "Group1",
        "Code": "Code1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Book1",
        "Group": "Group1",
        "Code": "Code1"
    }
]
```

I can't change table code because it's on another server.

How can I get the desired result from the input using Jsoup in Java?

Comment: have you tried anything? getting an error?

Comment: @Coder i edit question

Comment: You are using the same `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  problem with your code is you are trying to make use of same `jsonObject` and you are also using `JsonArray` which you don't need. You need an object containing `objects` but not object containing `array of objects`

```
public String TableToJson(String source) throws JSONException {   
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source);
        JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject();
        //JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                String Name = tds.get(0).text();
                String Group = tds.get(1).text();
                String Code = tds.get(2).text();
                String Lesson = tds.get(3).text();
                String Day1 = tds.get(4).text();
                String Day2 = tds.get(5).text();
                String Day3= tds.get(6).text();        
                jsonObject.put("Group", Group);
                jsonObject.put("Code", Code);
                jsonObject.put("Lesson", Lesson);
                jsonObject.put("Day1", Day1);
                jsonObject.put("Day2", Day2);
                jsonObject.put("Day3", Day3);
                jsonParentObject.put(Name,jsonObject);
             }
        }
    return jsonParentObject.toString();
}
```

Let me know if you need clarification!